# How can I make dynamically created dependent select/dropdowns using just jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with dynamically created rows, on each row I want to have 2 dropdowns/selects that are dependent on each other.
I have found 2 fiddles, the first is the exact output i want but the code is confusing and uses json. the second code is the easiest to understand but is not dynamic. Is there a way to make them work together?

```
// http://jsfiddle.net/C2xsj/5/ <----- this is the output i want but the code is kinda confusing for me

// https://jsfiddle.net/fwv18zo1/ <--- this has the simpler code
```

lets assume this is my table:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" id="button"/>
<form id="myForm">
<TABLE id="addTable" >
<TR><TD>
<select id="selectCategory">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>
</TD>
<TD>
<select id="selectSubCategory" >
    <option value="1">Banana</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="1">Orange</option>
    <option value="2">Wolf</option>
    <option value="2">Fox</option>
    <option value="2">Bear</option>
    <option value="3">Eagle</option>
    <option value="3">Hawk</option>
    <option value="4">BWM<option>
</select>
</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
</form>
```

when someone clicks the add row button, it creates a new row
using something similar to this all the options are coded into this function such as ():

```
$('#button').click(function() {
var table = $('#addTable');

table.append('<tr><td data-label="Task"><select class="ui fluid search dropdown" required><option value="1">Fruit</option><option value="2">Animal</option><option value="3">Bird</option><option value="4">Car</option></select><select class="ui fluid search dropdown" required><option value="1">Banana</option><option value="1">Apple</option><option value="1">Orange</option><option value="2">Wolf</option><option value="2">Fox</option><option value="2">Bear</option><option value="3">Eagle</option><option value="3">Hawk</option><option value="4">BWM<option></select></tr>');
}
```

so my issue is that since they cant all have the same id such as the ones in the fiddle, how i make the pair of selects on each row dependent

Comment: Add your code here instead... Stackoverflow can run code just like the fiddle.

Comment: its kinda hard to put my code here since theres a lot of sensitive info, il try and make a simplified version

Comment: Sensitive infos like `Banana` or `Eagle` ? 0_0

Comment: This is pretty straight forward, this is simply adding elements to the page on click... Especially given you have 2 examples to study from. Perhaps you should watch some tutorials to get a firmer understanding of DOM manipulation

Comment: Sorry, but there's a reason the system told you not to include fiddle-only questions.  Trying to get around this restriction may make you feel "clever" or superior but it's there for a reason and a sure way to get your question closed without even being looked at.

Comment: You can't put code here due to "Sensitive info" - but it's ok to put it in a fiddle?  Not sure that makes sense...

Comment: There some incongruities in your question: *"2 dropdowns/selects that are dependent on each other*" - fine, but then *"just JQuery"* with *"confusing and uses json"*, ok, but finally *"2nd is not dynamic"* - so where are you expecting to get the values for your drop downs from?

Comment: A third option would be to include a "2nd" `select` for each of the options on the first then show/hide the whole `select` that matches - no need to dynamically change `option`s

Comment: @freedomn-m Hopefully the edit makes sense now, i wont be able to have a whole select for each of the options in the first since the number of options is also dynamic and this will probably cause performance issues

Comment: Just an option.  I've voted to reopen as you've added some code.

Comment: *"so my issue is that since they cant all have the same id"* - it really wasn't (isn't) clear that the issue is about selecting the `select`s on multiple rows - it's there, but not clear, I guess the issue with the fiddle links clouded it.  The answer is to remove the `id` part and use relative DOM traversal and classes, eg `$(document).on("change", ".select1", function() { var ddl1 = $(this); 
 var ddl2 = $(this).closest("tr").find(".select2"); ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i used `clone` function. read comment on JS to know more.

```js
$(document).on("change",".select1",function(){
 var thisParent = $(this).parents("tr"); // detect the parent of the select1.
  $(".select2",thisParent).find('option[value]').addClass('hidden'); // hide all option values.
  $(".select2",thisParent).find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]').removeClass('hidden'); // show only values that match the 'select1' value.
});

$(".addNew").click(function(){ // clone button
 $(".cloneThis").clone().appendTo("tbody"); // clone the class 'cloneThis' and append it into tbody.
 $("tr:last").removeClass("cloneThis"); // remove 'cloneThis' class from the last appended child, so you can clone it again from the original one.
 $("button:last").removeClass("addNew").addClass("removeThis").html("Remove"); // replace 'Add' with 'Remove' and add class 'removeThis' to be able to remove this tr.
});

$(document).on("click",".removeThis",function(){ // remove function.
 $(this).parents("tr").remove(); // find this button parent and remove it.
});
```

```css
table{
 width:100%;
}

select, button{
 width:30%;
}

.hidden{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="cloneThis">
   <td>
   
   <select name="select1" class="select1">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
   </select>

   <select name="select2" class="select2">
    <option>Select type first</option>
    <option value="1" class="hidden">Banana</option>
    <option value="1" class="hidden">Apple</option>
    <option value="1" class="hidden">Orange</option>
    <option value="2" class="hidden">Wolf</option>
    <option value="2" class="hidden">Fox</option>
    <option value="2" class="hidden">Bear</option>
    <option value="3" class="hidden">Eagle</option>
    <option value="3" class="hidden">Hawk</option>
    <option value="4" class="hidden">BWM<option>
   </select>
   
   <button class="addNew">Add</button>
   
   </td>
  <tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```